# How can I create a URL rewrite rule for a domain-only request?

Tags: asp.net, .net, url, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

I am trying to create a URL rewrite for a site that has multiple domains. For example one of the domains is mydomain.com and if a user puts www.mydomain.com in their browser and does not specify a page I want to rewrite the URL to call www.mydomain.com/landingpage.aspx?cat=1&sol=4.

If the user calls anything else such as www.mydomain.com/somepage.aspx this rule should be ignored.

I have installed URL Rewrite 2.0 on the server 2008 R2 machine we have and I have added this rule to the web.config.

```
<rewrite>
<rules>
    <rule name="mydomain.com" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www.)?mydomain.com" />
            <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="^$" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="\landingpage.aspx?cat=1&sol=4" />
    </rule>
</rules>
</rewrite>
```

I am using the {PATH_INFO} of ^$ so that if anything other than just a call for the domain occurs this should ignore it I think. However it does not work.

I am using .NET 4.0 on the site.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong please?

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for following rule:

This will check if URL is empty i.e. no page is specified using match url=^$ - empty string and redirect to specific page.

```
<rule name="Redirect to specific page" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url="^$" />
   <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www.)?mydomain.com$" />
   </conditions>
   <action type="Redirect" url="http://{HTTP_HOST}/landingpage.aspx?cat=1&sol=4" />
</rule>
```